# Django: Fields from Parent class don't include in the child class table

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have three django models. A parent class and a two childs class.
What I am missing to get the parent class fields appear in the childs class tables

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    advertiser = models.CharField('Advertiser', max_length=100)
    insertion_order = models.ForeignKey(UserInsertionOrder,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    strategy = models.CharField('Strategy Name', max_length=300)
    creative = models.CharField('Creative Name', max_length=400)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.insertion_order
    
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'InserstionOrders'
        # abstract = True

class Child1(Parent):
    dsp = models.CharField('DV360', max_length=25)

class Child2(Parent):
    dsp = models.CharField('Xandr', max_length=25)
```

In my pgadmin, I don't see variables comming from Parent class.
I even got an error when I add abstract=True in the Parent class

Comment: Can you share what error you get when you used `abstract=True`, if you want to inherit `Parent` class's attributes and methods `abstract = True` is the way

Comment: Have you tried commenting out Meta.db_table variable and leaving `abstrac = True`? My guess is that both childs will have the same db_table which will override eachother.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want your Parent class to have its own database table ? Or do you want your child components to share the Parent class fields ?

If it's the second option then maybe you need your Parent class to be abstract. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes.

In your Parent Meta class you can :

- set `abstract = True`
- remove `db_table = 'InserstionOrders'` (an abstract class does not generate a database table)

If you want to use your Parent class and be able to instantiate it, then maybe your child components should use a many-to-one relationship (ForeignKey).